# Extract jSignature image from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to extract signature bitmap from `UIWebView`.

This is HTML code:

```
<canvas class="jSignature" width="200" height="120" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; height: 120px; width: 200px;"></canvas>
```

This code works in JS:

```
$('.signature').jSignature('getData','image')
```

This is my piece of code:

```
NSString *sign = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('.signature').jSignature('getData','image')"];
```

So `sign` is:

```
<object returned empty description>
```

Is there any way to get error message from `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Read doc of jSignature: http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/

So it should be:

```
NSString *sign = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('.signature').jSignature('getData')"];
```